# CSS Grid – grid-row span moving element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In this example, `e` gets inserted in the wrong place ( `grid-row: span 4` is making it move there since there is space for it there instead of making it span with the rows below the place it should be).

`f` and `g` stays in the right place ( with `grid-row: span 5`) yet the rows aren't "spanning" with the rows below…

Is there a way to make them (`e` - `f` - `g`) span with the rows below in this particular case as well as `e` to not get inserted elsewhere instead of where it is supposed to?

Below the code snippet you'll see what I want to achieve with this grid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a a a a a a a a a a"
    ". . . . . . . . . ."
    "b b b b b b b b b b"
    ". . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . c c c c c c c"
    ". . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . ."
    ". d d d e e f f g g"
    "h h h h . . . . . ."
    "h h h h . . . . . ."
    "h h h h . . . . . ."
    "h h h h . . . . . .";
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  height: 25px;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
  grid-row: span 4;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
  grid-row: span 4;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.f {
  grid-area: f;
  grid-row: span 5;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.g {
  grid-area: g;
  grid-row: span 5;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.h {
  grid-area: h;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
  <div class="e">e</div>
  <div class="f">f</div>
  <div class="g">g</div>
  <div class="h">h</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I want to achieve :
[image]

Comment: I edited the question with a minimal example for it to be easier to work with @VadimOvchinnikov

Comment: Here it is, undeleted @VadimOvchinnikov ;) "I could but I found out what was causing it to not work properly and it wasn't due to css grid itself but to my css to visualise the grid I was making. The problem was the `height:25px;` that I was giving each div to give them perspective with the border and grasp a better look of what I had. Though I will undelete it so you can post your solution, I'm eager to learn more about css grid and your solution will certainly get me to a better understanding of it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `25px` height of rows you can just add `grid-auto-rows: 25px` for grid container.

For achieving desired layout you can just change your `grid-tempate-areas` property value and remove all `grid-row` and `grid-column` definitions.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "a a a a a a a a a a"
    "b b b b b b b b b b"
    ". . . c c c c c c c"
    ". d d d e e f f g g"
    "h h h h e e f f g g";
  border: 2px solid red;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid lime;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
}

.f {
  grid-area: f;
}

.g {
  grid-area: g;
}

.h {
  grid-area: h;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
  <div class="e">e</div>
  <div class="f">f</div>
  <div class="g">g</div>
  <div class="h">h</div>
</div>
```